# call API once in a day automatically in Azure server

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, cron

I need to send a Push Notification once in a day, and I have created the API for the same. but I don't know how to run it from Azure Server.

I have read the below documentation but it is required some files to be uploaded but I want to run an API daily and once in a day.
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs

Do I have to create another project and upload in a WebJobs?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new project and create a webJob, but unless the Web Service you are deploying to has 'Always On' enabled, your app may be asleep when it should be starting.

Because of that I would actually recommend Azure Functions for this feature. under consumption plan  you are only charged for the amount of time the logic runs and the execution count.

The function will look something like this in C# Scripting

```
using System;

public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, IAsyncCollector<Notification> notification, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    await notification.AddAsync(new Notification(){
        // your code here

    });
}
```

**EDIT**

[instructions for Azure Notification Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs)

Comment: Just to confirm, when I create a `WebJobs` and it will call `Run` method with their arguments, am I right?

Comment: If you want to use Web Jobs, yes. 
What Price Plan is your service at?

Comment: I am on S3 plan

Comment: and what if I don't want to use the `WebJobs`

Comment: If you don't want to use web jobs, Create a Consumption Plan Function App and then create a function. Afterwards, add the above code and it should work fine after configuring the project.json

Comment: S3 has the 'Always On' feature under the application settings, so either is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145613/discussion-between-chandresh-khambhayata-and-robjam).